# How to check users session while clear browsers cache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, controller, server-error

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 application.

I have an issue with user's session logged out.

> > The problem is,i am getting the server error when i clear the browser's cache.

Below is the piece of code of Web.Config file :-

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2000" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120" />
```

Where we sets the loginUrl.

Below is the piece of code of controller :-

```
[CustomAuthorize(Privileges.CategoryCatalog)]
public class ProductController : ProductBaseController
{
      public ProductController ()
      {
        _changedBy = SiteContext.CurrentUser.CurrentUserDto.UsersID;
        _productId = (int)SiteContext.CurrentUser.CurrentUserDto.FKProductID;
      }
 }
```

> > And i want to add check on controller to check whether the user is logged out or not when we remove the browser's cache.

Comment: You can create and action filter wherein you can check the session if not then you can redirect to the login page. The Action Filter can be applied to selective controllers as well.

Comment: Please refer http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs for details on action filters

Comment: I wonder why you are employing asp-net-mvc and still thinking and trying to use Session belonged to classic-asp-net; why don't you prefer to utilize fresh and powerful facilities delivered by mvc?

Answer (score 0):

You can check session is empty or not to controller side.

Like ,

```
if(Session["UserName"] == null)
  // redirect to login page
```

This code help for when session is empty.